# What does the dot(.) symbol mean in R/how to interpret the code below?

Tags: r

Just wondering what it means the "dot" in the code below

```
data %>% .[. %in% rownames(data2)]
```

Comment: It is a placeholder for the data that has been passed from the left hand side of the pipe.

Comment: basically data is a character vector and data2 is a matrix(data frame), so I want to match what is in data to the rownames of data2.